# Unable to connect to ArcGIS Server in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-pro

I have an ArcGIS Server URL that I connect to no problem with ArcMap, but when I try to add it in ArcGIS Pro using any of the connection means available--it fails to connect. It asks me for my credentials but gives me an "unable to connect" error.

Has anyone else had this issue when migrating from ArcMap to ArcGIS Pro?

Answer (score 4):

If you save the server connection file created in ArcMap to a known folder (sometime its easier to copy to a known location other than the default location stored in ArcMap (*..\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.7\ArcCatalog*) try to browse to the folder and (right click) add the server connection to your ArcGIS Pro project.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I located the .asg file that ArcMap generated when I tried to connect to the server and copied it to a local drive like you suggested. But when I right clicked and added it in ArcPro, it still failed to establish the connection. It looks like the .asg file stores the server URL, but doesn't fix the server connection issue. Any thoughts on what to do next?

Comment: It should work as specified if credentials are correct.  Maybe some nuance we are missing.

Are you connecting to a stand-alone ArcGIS Server site or federated server (Portal)?  What type of connection did you create in ArcMap (user, publisher, admin)?
What version of server?

Assume you looked at the ArcGIS Pro documentation help?
https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/projects/connect-to-a-gis-server.htm

Comment: Thanks--it's a stand alone with a user connection. But we found the issue. Our organization had a different server that we needed to be accessing from ArcPro that they never told us about. :-) The joys of bureaucracy. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Worked for me, thanks!